# credentials do not match our records

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-8

I am currently working on POS in laravel 8. I am having an error when I login in that "credentials do not match our records" When I login in through the default Register page than it works fine but when I register through internal panel than the data goes to the database but I face error when I log in.

Code for registration through panel:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $users = new User;
    $users->name = $request->name;
    $users->email = $request->email;
    $users->password =  Hash::make($request->name);
    // $users->password =  bcrypt($request->name);

    $users->is_admin = $request->is_admin;
    $users->save();


    if($users){
        return redirect()->back()->with('User Created Successfully');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('User Failed Created');
}
```

Default register code:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panel registration form is hashing the `name` input and not the `password` input.

```
$users->password =  Hash::make($request->name);
```

Should probably be

```
$users->password =  Hash::make($request->password);
```

Answer (score 0):

#Code for registration through panel code should be like this#

```
public function store(Request $request){

$users = new User;

$users->name = $request->name;

$users->email = $request->email;

$users->password =  Hash::make($request->password);

$users->is_admin = $request->is_admin;

$users->save();

if($users){
    return redirect()->back()->with('User Created Successfully');
}
return redirect()->back()->with('User Failed Created');
```

}